# Can you start and execute a Jupyter Notebook in Sagemaker using Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I am planning to start a Jupyter Notebook instance and execute each notebook file in AWS Sagemaker using AWS Step Functions. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Step Functions Data Science SDK is an open source library that allows data scientists to easily create workflows that process and publish machine learning models using SageMaker and Step Functions.

The following [Example notebooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/howitworks-nbexamples.html), which are available in Jupyter notebook instances in the [SageMaker console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/) and the related [GitHub project](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/step-functions-data-science-sdk):

- hello_world_workflow.ipynb
- machine_learning_workflow_abalone.ipynb
- training_pipeline_pytorch_mnist.ipynb